# How to summarize data in Oracle SQL Developer with a query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Im practicing with the OE schema database on SQL Developer, and I cant figure out how to fix this issue. Im trying to get the total spent by customers summarized by the state and the year/month.

My sql code:

```
SELECT    
    c.cust_address.state_province,
    SUM(o.order_total) AS Total_of_Sales,
    TO_CHAR(o.order_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS Year_Month
FROM
    oe.customers c,
    oe.orders o
WHERE
    c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY
    c.cust_address.state_province,
    o.order_date
ORDER BY  
    o.order_date;
```

Result of query:

[[image: Result of query]]

However, as you can see here, the data of the state and YEAR/MONTH are still not grouped up. Instead, they have 3 rows for each state in the same month year when I need them to be summed it one.

May anyone guide me on how to correct my code to get my desired results?

Comment: I removed the irrelevant database tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  This is even more important if you are learning SQL.  Don't learn bad habits!

You need to aggregate by the `Year_Month` expression:

```
SELECT c.cust_address.state_province,
       SUM(o.order_total) AS Total_of_Sales,
       TO_CHAR(o.order_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS Year_Month
FROM oe.customers c JOIN
     oe.orders o
     ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.cust_address.state_province, TO_CHAR(o.order_date, 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(o.order_date, 'YYYY-MM');
```

In some databases, you could use the column alias (`Year_Month`) in the `GROUP BY`.  Oracle is not one of those databases.

Comment: Im a bit confused on what to follow, my last professor taught me to use JOIN and ON in my sql codes, now my new professors notes doesnt even include any of that so im just confused as to which way to follow. Also, all of his queries in the notes use commas as well which is why im following that way, but thank you for the tips and answering my question. Im gonna try and get it to work now

Comment: The explicit `JOIN` syntax was introduced with the ANSI-92 standard, nearly 25 years ago.  Perhaps it's time for your professor to go back to school.

Comment: @KurtLee - sorry to say, your professor is way behind the times. I hope you aren't paying too much to have such professors.

Comment: Although we don't support GROUP BY alias, we do support group by 3 ( in 12c ) :)

Comment: @BobC - I hope the only reason Oracle did that was to make it easier for people to migrate from other RDBMS's. `group by 3` should be banned (just like `order by 3`).

Comment: @mathguy. That's exactly why :)

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote?  It appears to be anonymous.

Comment: No idea.. but your solution worked perfectly when I ran the query

Answer (score 0):

You should use Year_Month    ... TO_CHAR(o.order_date, 'YYYY-MM') in group by  .. (and order by)

```
SELECT    c.cust_address.state_province,
          SUM(o.order_total) AS Total_of_Sales,
          TO_CHAR(o.order_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS Year_Month
FROM      oe.customers c,
          oe.orders o
WHERE     c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY  c.cust_address.state_province, TO_CHAR(o.order_date, 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY  TO_CHAR(o.order_date, 'YYYY-MM');
```

otherwise you obtain the same granularity of the o.order_date